# Javascript program for printing only capital letters and nothing else

Tags: javascript

I want my program to print only capital letters and nothing else. When I give console.log() command it prints everything and not just the capital letters. I cant find the fault.

```
function spinalCase(str) {
let arr=[];

arr=Array.from(str);

for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]==="A"||"B"||"C"||"D"||"E"||"F"||"G"||"H"||"I"||"J"||"K"||"L"||"M"||"N"||"O"||"P"||"Q"||"R"||"S"||"T"||"U"||"V"||"W"||"X"||"Y"||"Z"){
        console.log(arr[i]); //print only capital letters and nothing else
    }
}
}
spinalCase('This Is Spinal Tap');
```

Comment: `if (arr[i].toUpperCase() === arr[i] && arr[i].toUpperCase !== arr[i].toLowerCase())` - then you don't need to hardcode any letters ... and it should work for non-English letters as well - e.g š is lowercase, but Š is upper case

Comment: What have you tried to debug this?

Comment: simply `function spinalCase(str) {
    return Array.from(str).filter(c => [c.toLowerCase(), c.toUpperCase()].indexOf(c) === 1).join('');
}` - in the case of `spinalCase('This Iš Špinal Tap')` - outputs "TIŠT"

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here. You are saying `if arr[i] === "A"` OR string "B" OR string "C" ... etc (which will evaluate as true). Instead, you would have to write `arr[i] === "A" || arr[i] === "B" ...` But, I would look into Regex to make this a lot easier.

```
 if(arr[i]==="A"||"B"||"C"||"D"||"E"||"F"||"G"||"H"||"I"||"J"||"K"||"L"||"M"||"N"||"O"||"P"||"Q"||"R"||"S"||"T"||"U"||"V"||"W"||"X"||"Y"||"Z"){
        console.log(arr[i]); //print only capital letters and nothing else
    }
```

Comment: Regex may be an overkill here, but would surely look nicer. I would give a try to `if(arr[i]>="A" && arr[i]<="Z")`.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably misunderstanding the logical OR `||` operator and the concept of [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

> ```
> arr[i]==="A"||"B"||"C" ...
> ```

This DOES NOT compare `arr[i]==="A"` and `arr[i]==="B"`, etc. Instead it means, either `arr[i]==="A"` or `"B"` is not falsy, or `"C"` is not falsy, and so on. Since `"B"` is not falsy, that condition always evaluates to true.

So first of all you need to either write all those conditions separately,

```
arr[i]==="A" || arr[i]==="B" ...
```

Or, you can compare them using an array:

```
["A", "B", ..., "Z"].indexOf(arr[i]) >= 0
```